# "No such file or directory" when running cross compiled dart runtime

Tags: dart, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspbian

I'm running the cross compiled version of Dart runtime. The executable has been produced using the following instructions: https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/RaspberryPi

When I run it I get this error:

```
-bash: ./dart: No such file or directory
```

`ldd` output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/dart/runtime $ ldd dart 
    not a dynamic executable
```

`file` output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/dart/runtime $ file dart 
dart: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xb0dc8037ff83ff0742749241be56d7b8935efa6f, not stripped
```

Comment: `dart` exist in current directory? if not you should enter just `dart` without `./`

Comment: It is in the current directory.

Comment: What does following output show `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /usr/bin/dart`?

Comment: -bash: /home/pi/dart/runtime/dart: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) on RPi? What does it say to dart? "No such file or directory" points to the fact, that your binary has arch mismatch.

Comment: Added file and ldd output. I have the same suspect. I've used the dart wiki instruction with the suggested tool chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but I've found that using the last release of Raspbian (Debian Wheezy 2014-09-09) the executable works fine. So I think the cause is something old in my current Raspbian installation (I've updated it with the last updates but it is not sufficient).